Does "unburdened" describe "she" or "all" in the last sentence?
The following are captions below a picture of a cat sitting on a desk:

Everyone talked and laughed and smiled, and in the middle, our station cat, old and grey, tired, yet content and restful.
She watched as all about continued, unburdened.

My question is: What does the word "unburdened" at the end of the sentence describe? She (the cat) or all about?

Please, a full quotation and a source?

Without knowing the context, it's impossible to guess, though it presumably refers to all.

Cat has no worries?  She is unconcerned with what is going on.

The citation could never work in English.  If it was ever published, that was a mistake.
What might work is 'She watched as all about continued, unburdened' but that could go either way… either the watching cat, or 'all about' might be unburdened but the citation provides no useful clue.

So far as the syntax is concerned, the sentence is ambiguous, and this is the only thing that can be said about it on this site. The use of the comma, on which the other answer is based, is suggestive of one interpretation, but not dispositive. Any guesses that one may make about what the author intended would be outside the domain of this site.

Yes; the sentence fragment shows that the author may be somewhat cavalier in their use of English.

It refers to "she", the cat.
Normally it would refer back to the last noun ("all about") but the comma makes it refer to the subject of the previous clause.
Without the comma it would refer to "all about".

'The bridge remained standing as all the troops crossed, relieved.' like the original would be more idiomatic with further words after the absolute participial adjective ('relieved that they wouldn't have to build a pontoon'). But the claim about the directing force of the comma seems very dubious.

If there was no comma then "unburdened" would be a subject complement referring to "all" (cf "The boat continued undamaged"), but with the comma it could modify anything.

To me it's an inversion of "Unburdened, she watched ..." This version makes it clearer.
